# Generate a JSON file using Grunt-JSDoc

Tags: json, gruntjs, jsdoc

I use grunt-jsdoc. I can generate the whole documentation in HTML format but for my software I would like to generate it also in a JSON Format too. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried setting `explain: true` in the `options` object for your `jsdoc` task. For instance: `options: { explain: true, ... }` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried ... but had no effet. I found a solution no so elegant ... but working one. I register a new custom task and add JSDoc-X ... It does what I need ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found by myself by using JSDoc-X node module and use it inside a custom grunt task.